# Endorsement policy failure error is taking a long time in hyperledger fabric v2.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have discovery enabled and I am testing if a transaction will fail if the endorsing organizations set in the transaction do not match the organizations actually involved in the transaction.

I am attempting to create a private data collection with ORG1 and as part of the transaction I have used the following method to set the endorsing organizations:

`transaction.setEndorsingOrganizations(...['ORG2']);`

The test is failing but it is taking 60 seconds to do so.

The logs are as follows:

peer (org1) logs:

```
2021-01-25 13:31:50.876 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO 055 [default] Received block [15] from buffer
2021-01-25 13:31:50.878 UTC [vscc] Validate -> ERRO 056 VSCC error: stateBasedValidator.Validate failed, err validation of endorsement policy for collection _implicit_org_1 chaincode test-chaincode in tx 15:0 failed: signature set did not satisfy policy
2021-01-25 13:31:50.878 UTC [committer.txvalidator] validateTx -> ERRO 057 Dispatch for transaction txId = 5c52e14fa24a6e90effbd9dffcbb3fbc6cac1091c1bf3b6512616084 returned error: validation of endorsement policy for collection _implicit_org_1 chaincode test-chaincode in tx 15:0 failed: signature set did not satisfy policy
2021-01-25 13:31:50.878 UTC [committer.txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 058 [default] Validated block [15] in 1ms
2021-01-25 13:31:50.878 UTC [gossip.privdata] fetchPrivateData -> WARN 059 Do not know any peer in the channel( default ) that matches the policies , aborting
2021-01-25 13:31:50.878 UTC [gossip.privdata] populateFromRemotePeers -> WARN 05a Failed fetching private data from remote peers for dig2src:[map[{5c52e14fa24a6e90effbd9dffcbb3fbc6cac1091c1bf3b6512616084 test-chaincode _implicit_org_1 15 0}:[]]], err: Empty membership channel=default
2021-01-25 13:31:51.879 UTC [gossip.privdata] fetchPrivateData -> WARN 05b Do not know any peer in the channel( default ) that matches the policies , aborting
2021-01-25 13:31:51.879 UTC [gossip.privdata] populateFromRemotePeers -> WARN 05c Failed fetching private data from remote peers for dig2src:[map[{5c52e14fa24a6e90effbd9dffcbb3fbc6cac1091c1bf3b6512616084 test-chaincode _implicit_org_1 15 0}:[]]], err: Empty membership channel=default
2021-01-25 13:31:52.880 UTC [gossip.privdata] fetchPrivateData -> WARN 05d Do not know any peer in the channel( default ) that matches the policies , aborting
2021-01-25 13:31:52.880 UTC [gossip.privdata] populateFromRemotePeers -> WARN 05e Failed fetching private data from remote peers for dig2src:[map[{5c52e14fa24a6e90effbd9dffcbb3fbc6cac1091c1bf3b6512616084 test-chaincode _implicit_org_1 15 0}:[]]], err: Empty membership channel=default
```

fetchPrivateData and populateFromRemotePeers warnings repeat over and over until

```
2021-01-25 13:32:50.873 UTC [gossip.privdata] RetrievePvtdata -> WARN 0d4 Could not fetch all 1 eligible collection private write sets for block [15] (0 from local cache, 0 from transient store, 0 from other peers). Will commit block with missing private write sets:[txID: 5c52e14fa24a6e90effbd9dffcbb3fbc6cac1091c1bf3b6512616084, seq: 0, namespace: test-chaincode, collection: _implicit_org_1, hash: c189e3f3e8546ecde9b98b3aae67885cb8effeac1d35371a512c47db6a84
] channel=default
2021-01-25 13:32:50.873 UTC [validation] preprocessProtoBlock -> WARN 0d5 Channel [default]: Block [15] Transaction index [0] TxId [5c52e14fa24a6e90effbd9dffcbb3fbc6cac1091c1bf3b6512616084] marked as invalid by committer. Reason code [ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE]
2021-01-25 13:32:50.903 UTC [kvledger] CommitLegacy -> INFO 0d6 [default] Committed block [15] with 1 transaction(s) in 29ms (state_validation=0ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=11ms state_commit=16ms) commitHash=[bcfc168b343de9297a2cd4d9f202840dbde2478ab898998915b2c589]
2021-01-25 13:33:00.433 UTC [gossip.privdata] fetchPrivateData -> WARN 0d7 Do not know any peer in the channel( default ) that matches the policies , aborting
2021-01-25 13:33:00.433 UTC [gossip.privdata] reconcile -> ERRO 0d8 reconciliation error when trying to fetch missing items from different peers: Empty membership
2021-01-25 13:33:00.434 UTC [gossip.privdata] run -> ERRO 0d9 Failed to reconcile missing private info, error:  Empty membership
```

The problem isn't the result, it's the time it takes to return the error. Anyone know what could be causing this and is it expected behaviour to take this long? In the peer logs it looks like the validation of the endorsement policy fails right at the beginning, but then it continues to try and fetch the private data anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the core.yaml. The usual default setting is

```
    pvtData:
        pullRetryThreshold: 60s
```

That looks like the variable that might control that.